# How to close port 8080 from all except ip 127.0.0.1

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, iptables, port

I am on Centos 6 with Nginx on port 80 and Apache2 behind him on port 8080. I've written an anti DDOS script which works fine when ip access port 80, but if attacker directly spams port 8080 everything becomes bad. So I need to close 8080 with iptables to everybody except Nginx. Please help!

Comment: What have you tried to do so far?  Or are you asking us to lead you through the whole business of setting up a firewall on CentOS?

Comment: Duplicate:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7423309/iptables-block-access-to-port-8000-except-from-ip-address

Comment: sorry for duplicating, that was I needed!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two approaches here:

Force Apache to only be reachable from localhost by [binding](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mpm_common.html#listen) it to the loopback interface instead of listening to all ip-addresses

```
 # Listen 8080 
 Listen 127.0.0.1:8080
```

The second approach is configure the firewall where you only open port 80 for the general internet public. A basic firewall configuration can be created with `system-config-firewall-tui`.